# VBA : How to charge a binary file directly into a VB array?

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, file-io, binary

Let's say I'm exporting an array called `bigArray` directly into a binary file using :

```
Const myBinaryFile as String = "bigArray.bin"

Dim bigArray() as Variant
bigArray = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("bigArray").Range("A1:K100001").Value

Open myBinaryFile For Binary Access Write As #1
Put #1, 1, bigArray 
Close #1
```

How can I charge back this binary file directly into a array in VBA (ie without exporting as a .csv file or .text file) ?

I have no problem getting the data back from the binary file using :

```
Dim myBinaryData as String
Open myBinaryFile For Binary Access Read As #1
myBinaryData = Space$(LOF(1)
Get #1, , myBinaryData
Close #1
```

But is there some function to convert back myBinaryData into a VBA array ?

Comment: Read line by line and put it into the array. That's a way but I think you don't want that because it is gonna take forever.

Comment: @Masoud. Reading line by line from a *text file* is pretty straightforward and actually not that long (about less than 1s including conversion into the 2D array), but that's exactly what I'm trying **not** to do. Btw, how would you read "line by line" the raw binary data ?

Comment: when there's `\n` go to next index of the array?

Comment: The question is : how do you **read** the data ? Let's say I got it back in some `String` called `myData` (see in my post) , how do you read `myData` ? Can you propose some actual piece of code ?

Comment: You mean how to read binary data?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to read the binary file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142939/discussion-between-tibo-and-masoud).

Comment: https://www.devhut.net/2010/06/22/vba-converting-between-decimal-and-binary/

Answer (score 1):

To write/read the commands `Put` and `Get` can be used. Here an example how to write simple `UDT` named `DemoData`. It is important to know, what structure the binary data have in the file so it can be read correctly later. Note: be careful with strings. HTH

```
Option Explicit

Public Type DemoData
    Name As String * 30
    Age As Integer
    Weight As Double
End Type

Const myBinaryFile As String = "c:\Temp\StackOverflow\bigArray.bin"

Private Sub WriteData()
    Dim itm As DemoData
    Dim rw As Range
    Dim dt As Range
    Set dt = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("bigArray").Range("A2:C6")
    Open myBinaryFile For Binary Access Write As #1
        For Each rw In dt.Rows
            itm.Name = rw.Cells(1)
            itm.Age = rw.Cells(2)
            itm.Weight = rw.Cells(3)
            Put #1, , itm
        Next rw
    Close #1
End Sub

Private Sub ReadFile()
    Const rowsCount As Integer = 5
    Dim itms(1 To rowsCount) As DemoData
    Dim i As Integer
    Open myBinaryFile For Binary Access Read As #1
        For i = 1 To rowsCount
            Get #1, , itms(i)
        Next i
    Close #1
    For i = 1 To rowsCount
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("results").Cells(i, 1) = itms(i).Name
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("results").Cells(i, 2) = itms(i).Age
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("results").Cells(i, 3) = itms(i).Weight
    Next i
End Sub
```

> Data writen to bin file

[image]

> Data read from bin file

[image]

Note2: the name of the variable `rowsCount` is a little unfortunate. There are actually no rows in the binary file, just binary data. This variable should be named like e.g. `numberOfItems`. It just tells how many items are in the file so we can get then all to the array.

Comment: **Thanks** a lot for your very detailed answer. I see too major issues. **-1-** Accessing and writing 1,100,000 times in the worksheet would be way too long. **-2-** I don't know exactly how many rows might be in the file (only that it is a VB array saved in binary). **-1-** can be easily solved by putting the whole data in a bigArray and only writing it on the worksheet at the very end. Actually I won't even put the data in a worksheet at all (but only have it available as an `Array` (in RAM)). **-2-** However, this point is a NOGO for me since `numberOfItems`is expected to change (grow).

Comment: The need to **iterate** on each rows and columns (which is rather straightforward) and deal with data types when getting the data kind of defeat the whole purpose of trying too save 'bigArray' **directly** in binary. (If iterating is unavoidable to construct the 2D Array, then using a .csv file might make more sense, since it allow any number of rows and columns and is more flexible.). **--** What I'm looking for is how to "dump" the array (almost like "as stored in RAM") in a file, then charge it back (no question asked) into an array (in RAM). But that might will be illusory...

Comment: Do you know, what data are in the file? If yes, then its OK and thats actually all you need to know. The binary data are just a heap of binary data. You need to know how to read from this heap. If the binary file contains only integers for example, you just need to know how many of them are there. Then you just cut the integer-size pieces from the file one ofter another until all the items are in your array.Thats the way it works.

Comment: Data comes from a Reporting Services request and I do know what the columns content should look like (integer, text, text, decimal...). But I was willing/trying to **pre-process the raw data** in a way that let me charge it (on the fly) directly in memory (ie. in an array), without having to read the file line by line then reconstruct the array, so that it would be quicker, code would be simpler and the file would not readable by someone who didn't knew it was supposed to be charged in a VBA array. Since VBA let me dumping the array in binary, I thought charging it back might be possible.

Comment: I don't know any other way in VBA how you can read the binary data into an array except to read the file line by line. This array would be something like `Dim itms(1 To rowsCount) As DemoData` where `DemoData` would look like `(integer, text, text, decimal...)`. This `Write/Read Data` would be very fast. But maybe someone else knows how to put the data to the array in some `bulk-like` way, if that is what you are trying to achieve.I am aware only of the `line-by-line` way.